# How to give an NSOutlineView a tiled background image that scrolls?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I have a standard `NSOutlineView`. I would like it to have a background image, which tiles vertically, and which scrolls together with the outline view cells.

I've somewhat achieved this using the following in my ViewController:

```swift
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var outlineView: NSOutlineView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        if let image = NSImage(named: "tile") {
            let color = NSColor.init(patternImage: image)
            outlineView.backgroundColor = color
        }
    }
}
```

That works, except when you scroll past the top or bottom of the view (with the stretch provided by the containing scroll view).

[image]

I've tried putting the background image on the scroll view, but then it is static and doesn't scroll with the outline view's content.

I've also tried subclassing various objects in the view hierarchy and overriding their `draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect)` method and doing:

```swift
self.wantsLayer = true
self.layer?.backgroundColor = ...etc
```

but got no success from that either.

Can anyone provide any suggestions?

Comment: Did you draw `NSImage` directly to the view in `draw(...` method?

Comment: I don't recall trying that, no. It may well have worked? Anyway, I did find another solution, as posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a new custom `NSView`:

```
class MyView: NSView {

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        if let image = NSImage(named: "Tile") {
            let color = NSColor.init(patternImage: image)
            color.setFill()
            dirtyRect.fill()
        }

        super.draw(dirtyRect)
    }
}
```

Then in my `ViewController` class I added an instance of the custom view, and used autolayout constraints to pin the new view to my outlineView's clip view starting 2000points above it, and ending 2000 below. This means no matter how far you over-scroll into the stretch area, you still see the tiled background.

```swift
class MyViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var outlineView: NSOutlineView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        guard let clipView = self.outlineView.superview else { return }

        let newView = MyView(frame: .zero) // Frame is set by autolayout below.
        newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        clipView.addSubview(newView, positioned: .below, relativeTo: self.outlineView)

        // Add autolayout constraints to pin the new view to the clipView.
        // See https://apple.co/3c6EMcH
        newView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: clipView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        newView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: clipView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        newView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: clipView.topAnchor, constant: -2000).isActive = true
        newView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: clipView.bottomAnchor, constant: 2000).isActive = true
    }
}
```

I've removed other code from the above so hopefully I've left everything needed to illustrate the solution.